# GeoServer manual version ahead

Tags: geoserver

This is not a big deal but makes me wonder if I'm missing something as we use GeoServer.  Why is it that the official documentation is ahead of the release?  I've not seen any issues with that, but am curious.

Currently:

Downloads are for Version 2.22 (Maint), 2.23 (Stable), and 2.24 (Dev) @ https://geoserver.org/download/

Docs are for Version 2.25 @ https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/

Comment: This is really a question for the dev team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.geoserver.org/ is the official entry point for documentation.
There you can find links for the latest (the default) but also stable and maintenance.

[image]

Comment: That is true, but there really is some problem with the version numbers. Click on the "stable", the link goes to https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/ and the title on the page is "GeoServer 2.24.x User Manual". However, the stable is v. 2.23.2 https://geoserver.org/release/stable/.

Comment: That's an interim issue because 2.24 is in release candidate, not all bits are aligning. The site still says that 2.23.2 is stable, but in fact the 2.23.x branch is maintenance already (and 2.23.3 will show up as maintenance), and the new stable branch is already 2.24.x. In a couple of weeks what the docs say (published daily) and the web site says (published on releases) will align.